# Datatable is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using datatable to search the table content.but datatable cant work in my html code
I want to introduce filtering and sorting functionality to my table .all the table library included in the html script

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('table').dataTable();
    </script>
    <table style="margin-top:100px">
    <thead>
    <tr class='header'>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Party</th>
    <th>Constituency</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr>
    <th>pom</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>bachni</th>
    <th>male</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>santosh</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>bachni</th>
    <th>male</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>deepak</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>bachni</th>
    <th>male</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>sudhir</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>savarde</th>
    <th>male</th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What if you add the DOMReady event?

Comment: _...is not working_ - succinct, accurate and totally useless. Explain what is happening and what should happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code now  work fine:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('table').dataTable();
    </script>
    <table style="margin-top:100px" class="table table-striped table-bordered datatable dataTable">
    <thead>
    <tr class='header'>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Party</th>
    <th>Constituency</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr>
    <th>pom</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>bachni</th>
    <th>male</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>santosh</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>bachni</th>
    <th>male</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>deepak</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>bachni</th>
    <th>male</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>sudhir</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>savarde</th>
    <th>male</th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
<script>
$(function() {
      $('table').dataTable();
});
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[please check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/un7nL/)

Answer (score 2):

Since you've placed your script before your DOM, you need to put your jQuery code inside **[DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** handler `$(document).ready(function() {...});` or shorter form `$(function(){...}):`

This step is used to make sure all of your DOM elements have been loaded to the page before executing your jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
   $('table').dataTable();
});
```